# What is going to happen if my pending signals limit is exceeded?

Tags: linux, signals, ulimit

I'm blocking certain signals in my process, and I'm wondering what is going to happen if the pending signals limit is exceeded. 
Do the new ones get lost or is my process going to crash?

Comment: Did you try setting a low `ulimit -i` on your process that accumulates lots of pending signals and see what happens?...

Comment: I have now... And nothing seems to be happening :S Thx!